# how to make a plot with consecutive numbers in x and y axis?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I made this plot but I want consecutive numbers from 1 to 10 in the labels for the x and y axis. The current plot shows 0 then jumps to 5 and 10.

```
\tikzpicture
\begin{axis}[
axis y line=center, 
axis x line=middle,
axis equal,
grid=both,
xmax=10,xmin=-10,
ymin=-10,ymax=10,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
]
\addplot coordinates{(-3,1) (6,-2)};
\end{axis}
\endtikzpicture
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I cannot see the attached image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `\tikzpicture...\endtikzpicture`. It's just trouble. For tick labels you can use `xtick={-10,...,10}` to be added to the option list and same applies to y axis too. More is in the manual search for Section 4.15 Tick Options.